# Invertible Fourier integral

Tags: fourier-analysis, quantum-mechanics

I am reading a book on Schroedinger's equation and it says that

> "The relation between $\psi(x, 0)$ and $\phi(p)$ [where the latter is the amplitude in the $\psi(x,t)$ integral] is obtained by noting that [the Schroedinger equation] is a ***Fourier integral and thus can be inverted***."

May I ask what the ***bold*** bit means? Thanks.

Comment: Could you write the expression for $\psi(x, t)$ down?

Comment: Sure. $$\psi(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp\phi(p)e^{\frac{i(px-Et)}{\hbar}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bold bit is referring to the the [Fourier Inversion Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem).  Of course, the author is probably glossing over the requirements for convergence of the inverse fourier transform, but often the inverses exist as distributions.

Comment: Thanks. So that bit just means that we can make the function in the integral the subject function... Just out of curiosity are these ***"Fourier integrals"*** common?

Comment: Fourier integrals are just "Fourier transforms".

Comment: @H Taylor: as Jonas Teuwen says, Fourier Integrals are simply Fourier Transforms; therefore, they are quite common.